# React - Render HTML When Setting a State After Fetching Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application which needs to fetch invoice data from Stripe API (payment processor). When the invoice data has been returned, I'm trying to update my state using `this.setState({invoiceData: invoices})` where `invoices` is a string of HTML that I build out from the data returned from the Stripe API.

The issue is that the HTML isn't being rendered and is showing as plain text. I am pretty new to React and have only just got my head around rendering states, but now I'm pretty stuck on working this one out. What do I need to do to render the HTML? Please see my code below.

```
import React from 'react';

class BillingInvoices extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            invoiceData: false
        }
    }

    // When the 'BillingInvoices' component is mounted:
    componentDidMount() {

        // Get invoice data from Stripe API.
        fetch('/stripe-invoices', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                customerId: '128973982'
            })
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                console.log('Error with Stripe response');
            }
        })
        .then((stripeData) => {

            var invoiceCount = stripeData['result']['data'].length;
            var i;
            var invoices = '';

            for (i = 0; i < invoiceCount; i++) {
                invoices += '<div><a href="' + stripeData['result']['data'][i]['invoice_pdf'] + '" download>' + stripeData['result']['data'][i]['number'] + '</a></div>';
            }

            this.setState({
                invoiceData: invoices
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="billing-invoices">
                {this.state.invoiceData ? this.state.invoiceData : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BillingInvoices;
```

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: While you can show HTML using `_dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (but shouldn't), the proper way is to keep the returned data as is, then use JSX to turn it into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have looked at the JSX documentation but unfortunately couldn't work it out yet.

Comment: If you haven't been able to work it out yet I recommend a) searching online for a tutorial and/or b) breaking your problem into smaller pieces

Comment: @Matt Here's how: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xozr77o6l

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the resulted json in the component state is a good idea.

But then, you should deal with this json directly in your render method, using the power of JSX.

Check the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) about how to use JSX.

This is a dummy example of what your component could look like with the usage of JSX:

```
import React from "react";

class BillingInvoices extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    invoices: []
  }

  // When the 'BillingInvoices' component is mounted:
  componentDidMount() {
    // Get invoice data from Stripe API.
    fetch("/stripe-invoices", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        customerId: "128973982"
      })
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          this.setState(invoices: response.json());
        } else {
          console.log("Error with Stripe response");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="billing-invoices">
        {this.state.invoices.map((invoice, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>{invoice.name}</div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BillingInvoices;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read this particular guide many times, tried both `const` and `function` to try and render the HTML, but I'm not having any luck. Could you perhaps hint at which of those I'd need? Thank you.

Comment: I edited my previous answer to add some code sample.

Comment: My pleasure. Do not hesitate to accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can populate `invoiceData` with react components using JSX like so:

```
let invoices = (<div>{stripeData['result']['data'].map(data => (<div><a href={data['invoice_pdf']}  download>{data['number']}</a></div>))}</div>);

this.setState({invoiceData: invoices});
```

You can replace the content of the second `then` clause with the above and leave the rest of the code unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I've stripped out some of your code for my example to make it easier to read:

```
class BillingInvoices extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { invoiceData: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/stripe-invoices')
      .then((response) => response.ok && response.json())

      // Here I'm assigning the nested array to `invoiceData` immediately
      // so that you don't need to map over it later
      .then((data) => this.setState({ invoiceData:  data.result.data }));
  }

  render() {

    // Here we can check if the data exists. If it doesn't
    // show a loading icon (or something) until it is
    if (!this.state.invoiceData) <Loader />

    // ...otherwise show the data
    return (
      <div id="billing-invoices">

        // we map over the invoice data and for each invoice
        // return JSX (your div with an anchor populated with that invoice data)
        {this.state.invoiceData.map((invoice) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <a href={invoice.invoice_pdf} download>{invoice.number}</a>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      );
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```